# Does turtle have a on key press function that only repeats the function once

Tags: python, python-turtle

This is a bit of a weird question but I have a turtle game where I want it that every time the user presses the up arrow key the turtle moves but doesn't keep on moving if you hold it down. Is there a way you can do this with turtle? E.G: onkeyrelease or onkeypress, so that it only does the desired function once and not again until you click the key again?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Normally you'd do something like have a variable that you set to `True` when the user presses up, then don't allow the callback to do anything if that variable is already `True`. Then, have the "on release" callback reset the variable back to `False`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, why doesn't he use only onkeyrelease, and never worry about keep pushing!

Answer (score 0):

When you make games and want the user to move only once even if he keeps pushing a key, you should use onkeyrelease event in any programming language.

the module turtle has it's own events, you don't need to import any other module.

Here is a simple example

```
import turtle

m = turtle.Turtle()

def step():
  m.forward(50)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.onkeyrelease(step, "Right")
window.listen()
window.mainloop()
```

And here I made this for fun, you should try it :)

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
step = 25
t.speed(0)

# set the angles according to the mode
t_angles = [180, 0, 90, 270] if turtle.mode() == "standard" else [270, 90, 0, 180]
# standard mode | logo mode
# 0   -> east   | 0   -> north
# 90  -> north  | 90  -> east
# 180 -> west   | 180 -> south
# 270 -> south  | 270 -> west

def t_left():
  t.seth(t_angles[0])
  t.forward(step)

def t_right():
  t.seth(t_angles[1])
  t.forward(step)

def t_up():
  t.seth(t_angles[2])
  t.forward(step)

def t_down():
  t.seth(t_angles[3])
  t.forward(step)

def t_hide(a, b): t.penup()
def t_show(a, b): t.pendown()
def t_white(): t.color("white")
def t_red(): t.color("red")
def t_green(): t.color("green")
def t_blue(): t.color("blue")
def t_yellow(): t.color("yellow")
def t_default(): t.color("black")

window = turtle.Screen()
# press arrows to move around
window.onkeyrelease(t_right, "Right")
window.onkeyrelease(t_left, "Left")
window.onkeyrelease(t_up, "Up")
window.onkeyrelease(t_down, "Down")
# press these for changing color
window.onkeyrelease(t_white, "w")
window.onkeyrelease(t_red, "r")
window.onkeyrelease(t_green, "g")
window.onkeyrelease(t_blue, "b")
window.onkeyrelease(t_yellow, "y")
window.onkeyrelease(t_default, "d")
# press Esc to quit
window.onkeyrelease(window.bye, "Escape")
# press left button of the mouse to put the pen
window.onclick(t_show, 1)
# press right button of the mouse to hold the pen
window.onclick(t_hide, 3)
# listen to all the events
window.listen()
# keep the window open
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @SaymoinSam's extensive `onkeyrelease()` examples but they didn't work for me.  I believe the problem is the *operating system* implements *key repeat* and you can't defeat that directly from Python turtle.

An alternate approach is simply to disable the event handler inside the event handler:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle()

def step():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Right')
    turtle.forward(50)

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(step, 'Right')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

This will fire once, and only once.  If you want to *rearm* it, simply redo `screen.onkey(step, 'Right')` to setup another *one shot*.